# Formatting Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have a TOC that produces output as:

```
     Contents

One.........................1
   Falling..................1
Two........................10
   Rising..................10

Is it possible for the TOC to produce output as:

Falling.....................1
Rising.....................10
                             etc.
```

The Chapter Subheadings are produced from the following code:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
font=\fontsize{20}{15}
]{section}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}}
```

This is an MWE of the problem:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,english,british,twoside,openany,headings=small]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{ms_mystyles} \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Palatino}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }

\RedeclareSectionCommand[ font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde font=\fontsize{20}{15} ]{section}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{35}{30}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}}
     \begin{document}
        \pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
            \tableofcontents
            \addchap{Tryout}
            \addsec{Simple Heading}
        \mainmatter
        \addchap{ONE}
        \addsec{Falling}
        \input{Some text}
            \end{document}
```

Comment: may be there is better ways but you can do it by adding `\renewcommand*\chaptertocdepth{5}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\scr@tso@section@indent{0pt}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work just fine, except that the page numbers in the 'frontmatter' e.g. Preface, are not added resulting in the following: Preface.......................  - no page number visible? Any ideas?

Comment: this is because of `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in your code.  **Edit** there is no page number.

Comment: I already commented this line of code out - and your answer confirmed I had done the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With KOMA-Script version 3.20 or newer you can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocstyle=gobble]{chapter}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocstyle=gobble]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Tryout}
\addsec{Simple Heading}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\mainmatter
\addchap{ONE}
\addsec{Falling}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0pt]{section}
\renewcommand*\addchaptertocentry[2]{}
```

That works also with KOMA-Script versions older than 3.20.

Note that `\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=<fontsettings>]{section}` does the same as `\setkomafont{section}{<fontsettings>}`. The last usage wins.

Comment: esdd - why the option [2016/05/10]? Does this option call the 3.20 version of {scrapbook}?

Comment: @Mike With `\documentclass{scrbook}[2016/05/10]` you will get a warning if an older version of `scrbook` is used to compile the file. Note that option `tocstyle=gobble` was introduced in version 3.20.